# Shift+C no longer working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I am not sure why and quite saddened by this but I can no longer type a capital 'C' on my keyboard for my Mac mini running OS X Yosemite. I have run through all of the shortcuts in *System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts*, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not listed there, anywhere...

What is causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: And for context, the (5) capitalized C's above were entered with Cap Locks! XX(

Comment: Have you take that keyboard to another conputer or tried another keyboard on the Mac Mini? My suspicion is a hardware failure is causing this.

Comment: Oh.. My... Goodness - it was just the keyboard!!!! This fixed it, I just swapped. Thank you bmike!!!! Please toss this in as a formal question answer so I can mark as 'solved' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken that keyboard to another computer or tried another keyboard on the Mac Mini?

The most elegant solution to your problem would be if it's a hardware issue on that specific keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your keyboard is working properly. That would be a great first step in figuring out if there is a problem with the hardware. If it is not your keyboard, then I would try to turn of your Mac and turn it back on. If the problem still persists, then you would actually have to add a shortcut yourself

- Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Keyboard.
- Click Shortcuts, select App Shortcuts, then click Add (+).
- Click the Application pop-up menu, then choose an app. If you want to
  set the same key combination for a menu command that appears in many
  apps, choose All Applications.
- If the app you want to select doesn’t appear in the list, choose
  Other, then locate it using the Open dialog. Some apps may not allow
  you to set keyboard shortcuts.
- Type the menu command for which you want to set a keyboard shortcut
  in the Menu Title field.
- You must type the command exactly as it appears in the Application
  menu, including ellipses and any other punctuation. To type an
  ellipsis, use three periods without spaces.
- Click in the Keyboard Shortcut field, press the key combination that
  you want to assign to the menu command, then click Add (+).
- You can’t use each type of key (for example, a letter key) more than
  once in a key combination.
- Quit and restart any apps you’re using for the new keyboard shortcut
  to take effect.
- If you assign a keyboard shortcut that already exists for another
  command or another app, your new shortcut won’t work. Find the menu
  command that’s using it, then reassign the keyboard shortcut for that
  item.
- To remove a customized shortcut, click Delete (–).

Comment: I would make the short cut like this=

Comment: How does this address the problem of a non-working "Shift-C" key combination?

Comment: @patrix He can add his own combination such as CAPS-C-CAPS to SHIFT-C to address the problem of a nonworking shift c comination

Comment: Using CAPS instead of Shift doesn't need any shortcuts at all. Shortcuts are used to access menu commands, not standard letters.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue it was because i had SHIFT-C bound to toggle mute in skype